# Google Fonts vs. The fonts installed on your computer

Tags: html

Are Google Fonts as reliable as the standard fonts shipped with PCs, in terms of browser compatibility?  Right now we upload a lot of custom fonts for our site, but we have some issues with various browsers (even across web standards).  Some say just go with Helvetica, Arial and the usual suspects for across the board rendering accuracy.  But do Google Fonts offer creative solutions without sacrificing rendering accuracy?

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes.

Web fonts are great, but you need to remember that if the content delivery network is down then users will not get the font, so make sure you include fallbacks in your font-family all the way down to either serif or san-serif.

The other option is to package the fonts you want to use so that users can download them if they are missing, but the packaging and delivery process is pretty cumbersome. Also you might run into licensing issues.

Comment: isn't google's "content delivery network" pretty bullet proof?

Comment: Yea it is. I have never seen it down.